# Subir Imagen con laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, imagen

estoy intentado hacer un formulario para agregar usuario, pero no tengo idea de como subir la imagen al servidor.
Tengo lo siguiente en la vista

create.blade.php

```
<form class="form-material form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('users') }}" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    @if ($errors->any())
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <h6>{{ __('Please correct the errors below') }}:</h6>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <label class="col-md-12" for="image"><span>{{ __('Image') }}:</span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-md-12">

                                <input type="file" id="image" name="image" class="form-control text-muted"  placeholder="{{ __('Enter your') }} {{ __('image') }}" value="{{ old('image') }}">
                                @if($errors->has('image'))
                                    <p>{{ $errors->first('image') }}</p>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">{{ __('Submit')}}</button>
                    </form>
```

Y en el UserController.php

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function store()
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'unique:users,email'],
            'password' => 'required|min:8|max:255',
            'image' => 'required', //|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',

        ],[
            'name.required' => 'El campo nombre es obligatorio'
        ]);

        User::create([
            'image' => $data['image'],
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('users.index');
    }
```

En el filesystems.php tengo lo siquiente:

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/assets/images/users',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

Agradeceré que puedan ayudarme a subir la imagen al direcctorio /assets/images/users

Answer (score 0):

Si te fijas al hacer un `request()->file('imagen')` te dará un objeto .

Para guardarla solo tienes que usar `store`o `storeas` como cualquiera de estos 3 ejemplos.

```
request()->file('imagen')->store('public');

$path = Storage::putFile('imagen', request()->file('imagen'));

$path = request()->file('imagen')->storeAs(
    'public', request()->user()->id
);
```

[DOCUMENTACIÓN](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo usar Storage, yo lo uso de la siguiente manera:

1.- Para configurar pega esto en config > filesystem.php, en el array disks

```
'uploads' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path(),
    ],
```

Te quedaria algo asi:

```
'disks' => [
        .
        .
        .
        .
    'uploads' => [
          'driver' => 'local',
          'root' => public_path(),
     ]
        .
        .
        .
        .
]
```

2.- En tu Controlador importas Storage

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
```

3.- Guardar un archivo, usando la siguente sintaxis

> storeAs( ruta_de_carpeta_en_el_servidor , nombre_del_archivo , 'uploads' );

```
$data['imagen']->storeAs('/assets/images/users','user_122_22.png','uploads');
```

4.- En vez de guardar en la BDD una imagen solo guardas el nombre del archivo en un string, **ten en cuenta guardar el nombre con el tipo de archivo, ejemplo: user_1232.png ó user_1232.jpg.....**

```
 User::create([
        'image' => $data['image'], // Tipo String solo con el nombre de la imagen que posee al ser guardada en el servidor, en este caso seria: user_122_22.png
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password'])
    ]);
```

5.- Para acceder a la imagen desde BLADE

```
{{asset('assets/files/images/users/'.$user->image)}}
```

6.- Para borrar una imagen del servidor

```
Storage::disk('uploads')->delete('assets/images/users/'.$user->image);
```

PD: *cuando hago referencia a* **$user->imagen** *es solo el nombre de la imagen guardada en la Base de Datos*